# How can I group on a nested property as well as having the same parent in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm new to `LINQ`, and I'm having trouble organizing this query to return what I want. First off, some background. I'm working on a music game, which supports custom notecharts. Notecharts contain metadata specific to a collection of notes, such as number of notes, difficulty, and BPM. One or more notecharts can be in a simfile, sort of a container of notecharts. A simfile has its own "simfile-level" metadata as well, such as a path to a song file, song title, song artist, etc. So, I have classes of the following form:

```
class Notechart {
    public List<Note> Notes { get; }
    public uint BPM { get; set; }
    public uint Difficulty { get; set; }
}

class Simfile {
    public List<Notechart> Notecharts { get; }
    public string SongPath { get; set; }
    public string SongTitle { get; set; }
    public string SongArtist { get; set; }
    // Other "album-specific" fields...
}
```

For a given `List<Simfile>`, I'd like to get a list of all `Notecharts` contained in all the `Simfiles` grouped by the following criteria (in order of precedence):
  1) The value of `Notechart.<Value>`, where `<Value>` is any of the notechart-specific fields or a transformation of a notechart-specific field (e.g. any BPMs between 130-150)
  2) Being in the same `Simfile` (since if two notecharts within a simfile have the same criteria as above, I would want to display them together with information from the simfile)

Is there anyway to represent this in `LINQ`? `MyElement` and `MyElementCollection` don't implement any custom equality checking, so I don't believe testing if it is in the list will work. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your latest updates and now I'm not sure if my answer is what you need...

Comment: Hmm, working on a StepMania app?  :)  It's much easier to visualize your problem now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass an anonymous type as the grouping key to group over multiple values:

```
void Sample(INumerable<SimeFile> simeFiles, Func<NoteChart, bool> noteChartPredicate)
{
  var xyz =
    from sf in fimFiles
    from nc in sf.NoteCharts
    group nc by new{Matched=noteChartPredicate(nc), SimFile=sf} into g
    select new{g.Key.SimFile, g.Key.Matched, NoteCharts = g.ToList()};
  ...
}

Sample(simFiles, nc => nc.BPM >= 130 && nc.BPM <= 150);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're missing is the SelectMany extension method. Try this:

```
List<MyElementCollection> elementCollections = ...;
var grouped = (from ec in elementCollections
               select new
               {
                   ElementCollection = ec,
                   GroupedElements = (from e in ec.Elements
                                      group e by e.Value into g
                                      select new
                                      {
                                          Value = g.Key,
                                          Elements = g
                                      })
               });
```

Comment: Missed that. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's a lot easier to visualize your problem now with a more complete example (particularly with something I'm familiar with).  Ultimately the query I had mostly stays the same.  To get the kind of grouping you want, you should define a helper class to classify BPM ranges.

```
public class BpmRange
{
    static uint[] thresholds = new uint[] { 0, 60, 80, 100, 120, 140, 160, 180, 200, 220, 240, 260, 280, 300, uint.MaxValue };
    public static BpmRange GetRange(uint bpm)
    {
        var index = Enumerable.Range(1, thresholds.Length - 1).First(i => bpm < thresholds[i]);
        return new BpmRange(thresholds[index - 1], thresholds[index]);
    }
    private BpmRange(uint lowerInclusive, uint upperExclusive) { range = Tuple.Create(lowerInclusive, upperExclusive); }
    private Tuple<uint, uint> range;
    public uint LowerInclusive { get { return range.Item1; } }
    public uint UpperExclusive { get { return range.Item2; } }
    public override bool Equals(object obj) { var asRange = obj as BpmRange; return asRange != null && this.range.Equals(asRange.range); }
    public override int GetHashCode() { return range.GetHashCode(); }
    public override string ToString() { return String.Format("[{0}, {1})", LowerInclusive, UpperExclusive); }
}

List<Simfile> simfiles = ...;
var query = from sim in simfiles
            select new
            {
                Simfile = sim,
                ByRange = from chart in sim.Notecharts
                          group chart by BpmRange.GetRange(chart.BPM)
            };
```

Comment: p.s., The examples given make it seem like you are not particularly interested in the `MyValue` instance (looks odd to have groupings of the same value).  It looks like you're just trying to do counting which you could do without keeping the group around.

Comment: I'll update with a more realistic and concrete example. It has to do with needing to access data from both a particular MyElement as well as the MyElementContainer that contains it.

Comment: @Mark: Definitely makes a lot more sense now.  I've updated my answer to correspond to your updated question.